# sending query based on current route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Current solution:

example url:

```
http://localhost:3000/credit_cards?category=3
```

Application Route:

```
@controllerFor('creditCards').set 'content', App.CreditCard.find(category_id: getUrlParam('category'))
```

Get Url Params helper:

```
window.getUrlParam = (name) ->
  paramsString = $(location).attr('search').substring(1)
  urlParamsArray = paramsString.split('&')

  for param in urlParamsArray
    paramPair = param.split('=')
    paramName = paramPair[0]
    paramValue = paramPair[1]
    return paramValue if paramName is name
```

Is there something better? Does Ember have it built-in out of the box?

Please note that Ember app is only a part of the app - it sits under its own root container. All the other elements are static.

Comment: Query strings are work-in-progress at the moment. See this [issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1773)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there something better?

Depends. I'm assuming you need the query parameter because ember app is only part of your app.  In that case your solution seems like a good one. Otherwise using a url like /credit_cards/3 instead would be `better`.

> Does Ember have it built-in out of the box?

No. There is an experimental library available:

https://github.com/alexspeller/ember-query

Seems that might be overkill given how simple your example is, but if you are doing a lot of work with queryString I would recommend checking it out.